# Why the job chaining not working in mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I create two jobs, and I want to chain them, so that one job is executed just after the previous job is complete. So I wrote the following code. But as I have observed job1 finished correctly, and job2 never seems to execute.

```
public class Simpletask extends Configured implements Tool {
public static enum FileCounters {
    COUNT;
}
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text>{

      public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
          while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
              String line = itr.nextToken();
              String part[] = line.split(",");
              int id = Integer.valueOf(part[0]);
              int x1 = Integer.valueOf(part[1]);
              int y1 = Integer.valueOf(part[2]);
              int z1 = Integer.valueOf(part[3]);
              int x2 = Integer.valueOf(part[4]);
              int y2 = Integer.valueOf(part[5]);
              int z2 = Integer.valueOf(part[6]);
              int h_v = Hilbert(x1,y1,z1);
              int parti = h_v/10;
             IntWritable partition = new IntWritable(parti);
             Text neuron = new Text();
             neuron.set(line);
             context.write(partition,neuron);
          }
}
public int Hilbert(int x,int y,int z){
          return (int) (Math.random()*20);
      }
  }

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text> {

private Text result = new Text();
private MultipleOutputs<IntWritable, Text> mos;
public void setup(Context context) {
    mos = new MultipleOutputs<IntWritable, Text>(context);
}
<K, V> String generateFileName(K k) {
       return "p"+k.toString();
}
public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String accu = "";
    for (Text val : values) {
        String[] entry=val.toString().split(",");
        String MBR = entry[1];
        accu+=entry[0]+",MBR"+MBR+" ";
    }
    result.set(accu);
    context.getCounter(FileCounters.COUNT).increment(1);
    mos.write(key, result, generateFileName(key));
}
}

public static class RTreeMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text>{
  public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   System.out.println("WOWOWOWOW RUNNING");// NOTHING SHOWS UP!
  }
  }

public static class RTreeReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text> {
private MultipleOutputs<IntWritable, Text> mos;
Text t = new Text();

public void setup(Context context) {
    mos = new MultipleOutputs<IntWritable, Text>(context);
}
public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    t.set("dsfs");
    mos.write(key, t, "WOWOWOWOWOW"+key.get());
//ALSO, NOTHING IS WRITTEN TO THE FILE!!!!!
}
}
public static class RTreeInputFormat extends TextInputFormat{
 protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path file) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
           System.err.println("Enter valid number of arguments <Inputdirectory>  <Outputlocation>");
           System.exit(0);
          }
          ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Simpletask(), args);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Job1");
    job.setJarByClass(Simpletask.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
    boolean complete = job.waitForCompletion(true);

    //================RTree Loop============
    int capacity = 3;
    Configuration rconf = new Configuration();
    Job rtreejob = Job.getInstance(rconf, "rtree");
    if(complete){
        int count =  (int) job.getCounters().findCounter(FileCounters.COUNT).getValue();
        System.out.println("File count: "+count);
        String path = null;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            path = "/Worker/p"+i+"-m-00000";
            System.out.println("Add input path: "+path);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(rtreejob, new Path(path));
        }
        System.out.println("Input path done.");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(rtreejob, new Path("/RTree"));
        rtreejob.setJarByClass(Simpletask.class);
        rtreejob.setMapperClass(RTreeMapper.class);
        rtreejob.setCombinerClass(RTreeReducer.class);
        rtreejob.setReducerClass(RTreeReducer.class);
        rtreejob.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        rtreejob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        rtreejob.setInputFormatClass(RTreeInputFormat.class);
        complete = rtreejob.waitForCompletion(true);
}
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: This thing is written in main class. I looked up for some method saying I should use JobClient, but as I also want to customize the inputformat to read multiple files, and JobClient does not seem to support that?

Comment: FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1])) will be present, it might fail for that.

Comment: You can see this example to understand a basic structure of job chaining. 
https://github.com/Rachitahuja20/Hadoop-learning/tree/master/MapReduceJobChain/src/main/java/com/aamend/hadoop/MapReduce

Answer (score 2):

For a mapreduce job, the output directory should not exists. It will check for the output directory first. If it is exists, the job will fail. In your case, you specified the same output directory for both the jobs. I modified your code. I changed the args[1] to args[2] in the job2. Now the third argument will be the output directory of second job. So pass a third argument also.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Job1");
    job.setJarByClass(Simpletask.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    //AND THEN I WAIT THIS JOB TO COMPLETE.
    boolean complete = job.waitForCompletion(true);

    //I START A NEW JOB, BUT WHY IS IT NOT RUNNING?
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf, "Job2");
    job2.setJarByClass(Simpletask.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job2.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[2]));
```

Comment: This is just an example for the job chaining pattern, but actually there is no compiler error regarding the path problem. The key is that I write the driver function like it, and the second job does not run.

Answer (score 1):

A few possible causes of errors:

1. `conf` is declared twice (no compile error there?)
2. The output path of job2 already exists, as it was created from job1 (+1 to [Amal G Jose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31739084/2516301))
3. I think you should also use `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);` and `job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);` for both jobs.
4. Do you also have a command to execute job2 after the code snippet that you posted? I mean, do you actually run `job2.waitForCompletion(true);`, or something similar to that?

Overall: check the logs for error messages, which should clearly explain what went wrong.

Comment: This is just an example. Actually I use different options and paths for the second job, the key is that. EVEN IF I write the driver function in that way, the second job is not running.

Comment: @fTTTTT Then, what are the differences that you make? Can you update the question with the actual code that you are running?

Comment: Hi I have updated the real code I am running, it is just two jobs containing two mapper and reducer, and I drives them in the way I previously show. The second mapper does not output any result to the screen (while I add print to console in the mapper task) Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have updated the program, the key is to know if such pattern can be used for chaining jobs in mapreduce. (Without using other functions such like client)

Comment: @fTTTTT does it print to console any of the system outs? if not, then maybe the first job did not succeed, so `complete` is false. Did you check the logs (the log files of hadoop not the console) for any errors?